# #states doesn't work with exposed filters

Tags: 7, views, javascript

I have two exposed filters Contry (name=field_country_tag_tid) and City (name=field_country_tag_tid_option_limit). Reference limit option Module limet avaliale options in city but not when page with filters loaded at first time. That why I wanted to desable City Filter by using #states

```
function mymodue_form_views_exposed_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'views_exposed_form' && $form_state['view']->name == 'map') {
   $form['field_country_tag_tid_option_limit']['#states'] = array(
  'visible' => array('select[name="field_country_tag_tid"]' => array('value' => '1')),
       );

    }
}
```

I used the following example http://api.drupal.org/api/examples/form_example!form_example_states.inc/function/form_example_states_form/7

But there are no any changes in my exposed filter, where is my mistake? Thanks

Comment: I tried to use "id" instead of "name" and now it works!:)

Comment: put your solution as an answer and check it so others may see the solution. Comments are not visible as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to use `id` instead of `name` and now it works!